# Redirect contact page to the same page and add message too

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, contact-us, contact-form

I use magento 1.9.x version, I add a new contact form in product view page, but after I press Submit button the magento is redirect me to the Contact page how I can stop this redirect and remain in the same page.

I try to put this code in contact controller

```
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
           if(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(true)){
            $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(true)); 
            }
             else{
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            }
```

is work is stay in the same page but I don't see that success message:

"`Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.`"

How I can add that message too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have put `global_messages` block on your page.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
```

Also try with below code.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
```

Comment: Hi, your below code is work perfectly, thank you so much